# codeigniter session custom data lost, but not on localhost

Tags: database, codeigniter, session

I have this weird problem with my ci sessions.
On localhost is works fine, but online the log shows the error:

> The session cookie data did not match what was expected. This could be
>   a possible hacking attempt.

I removed all cookies and emptied the sessions table. I also set user_agent length to 255. Basepath is also correct. What is notice when I log the session id's is the following:

On the login page and when checking username/pw the id is the same, then I go to my members area where the id has changed.

Another example:
1. I go to members area, session id is set, i'm not logged in, im sent to login
2. On login page, session id is changed, i login
3. Validation, session id is unchanged, i'm validated and sent to members area
4. On members area, session id is changed, i'm not logged in.

On the login page, my sessions table counts 0 rows, when i login the sessions table counts 2/3 rows. 1 of them, but not the one with the current session id holds all the correct data.

Hopefully someone can help me with this.

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9007282/ci-2-0-3-session-heisenbug-session-is-lost-after-some-time-20-minutes-only-on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Codeignitor native php session library has the problems. It cause the problems that you are describing because if the cookies is not set, it won’t set. Furthermore it won’t be able to recognize the session. In order to avoid this problem you can use [Native Session Class](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/Native_session/)

Here are few links to support my answer.
[Problems with cookies / MAMP / Codeingiter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868177/problems-with-cookies-mamp-codeingiter)
http://myphplibrary.blogspot.in/2012/03/codeigniter-session-issue-fixation.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've read the same thing somewhere else. I'll have to go for the Native Session Class then. Thanks.

Comment: ..and the magic has happened. The NS Class works like a charm!

Comment: I also had this problem, but just recently. Sessions used to work properly. Anyway, the native session solved the problem, but, does it suffer from the same "session timeout" problem that was so famous in the CI_Session?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things to check;

1. The server local time vs your local time - perhaps the cookie is expiring as it is set? To confirm - set the $config['sess_expiration'] time to like 9999999 and see if it works
2. Turn off $config['encrypt_cookie']
3. Turn off $config['sess_match_ip']
4. Make sure you have set the correct cookie information:

   ```
   $config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
   $config['cookie_domain']    = // YOUR DOMAIN
   $config['cookie_path']      = // YOUR BASE URI
   $config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
   ```

Comment: I actually had all the settings (except sess_expiration) already set as you descripbed. It didn't work though. Thanks anyway.